# Prettier does not apply when eslint accuses max-length and .prettierignore does not work

Tags: reactjs, eslint, prettier, typescript-eslint

**Case 1** (`PrintWidth`):

What happens in this case is the following, I have configured printWidth in the `.prettierrc` file, in the **vscode** `settigns.json` and in the `.eslintrc.js`. However, when reaching the `max-length`, which in this case is `120`, the `prettier` does not apply its styling.

**Case 2** (`.prettierignore`)

The `prettier` simply ignores this file and does not apply the rules it contains.

**Desired resolution for Case 1:**

When `eslint` verifies that the code is at the limit of the line size, which in this case is 120 and greater than the limit, it "breaks" the code, such as, for example, lowering the properties of the `JSX components` etc.

**Desired resolution for Case 2:**

That the `prettier` can use the `.prettierignore` file

**MY VSCODE SETTINGS:**

```
"editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"editor.rulers": [120, 120]
```

**MY PRETTIER CONFIG:**

```
{
    "printWidth": 120,
    "tabWidth": 2,
    "useTabs": true,
    "semi": true,
    "singleQuote": true,
    "jsxSingleQuote": true,
    "jsxBracketSameLine": false,
    "bracketSpacing": true,
    "arrowParens": "always",
    "endOfLine": "lf",
    "quoteProps": "as-needed",
    "trailingComma": "none"
}
```

**MY ESLINTRC CONFIG:**

```
module.exports = {
    env: {
        browser: true,
        es2021: true
    },
    extends: [
        'plugin:react/recommended',
        'plugin:react-hooks/recommended',
        'plugin:prettier/recommended',
        'plugin:import/errors',
        'plugin:import/warnings',
        'react-app',
        'react-app/jest',
        'airbnb'
    ],
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
    parserOptions: {
        ecmaFeatures: {
            jsx: true
        },
        ecmaVersion: 5,
        sourceType: 'module'
    },
    plugins: ['react', 'react-hooks', 'prefer-arrow', 'prettier', '@typescript-eslint'],
    settings: {
        react: {
            version: 'detect'
        },
        'import/resolver': {
            node: {
                paths: ['src'],
                moduleDirectory: ['node_modules', 'src/'],
                extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx']
            }
        }
    },
    overrides: [
        {
            files: ['**/*.js', '**/*.jsx', '**/*.ts', '**/*.tsx'],
            plugins: ['@typescript-eslint'],
            rules: {
                'no-use-before-define': 'off',
                '@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define': ['error']
            }
        }
    ],
    ignorePatterns: ['src/assets/images/*', 'src/assets/fonts/*'],
    rules: {
        '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars': ['error'],
        'prettier/prettier': 'error',
        'arrow-body-style': 'off',
        'arrow-parens': ['error', 'always'],
        'object-curly-newline': 'off',
        'no-tabs': 0,
        indent: [2, 'tab', { SwitchCase: 1 }],
        'comma-dangle': ['error', 'never'],
        'max-len': ['error', { code: 120 }],
        'jsx-quotes': ['error', 'prefer-single'],
        'implicit-arrow-linebreak': 'off',
        'operator-linebreak': [
            'error',
            'after',
            {
                overrides: {
                    ':': 'before'
                }
            }
        ],
        'react-hooks/rules-of-hooks': 'error', // Checks rules of Hooks
        'react-hooks/exhaustive-deps': 'warn', // Checks effect,
        'react/jsx-indent-props': 'off',
        'react/react-in-jsx-scope': 'off',
        'react/jsx-props-no-spreading': 'off',
        'react/jsx-boolean-value': 'off',
        'react/jsx-indent': ['error', 'tab', { checkAttributes: true, indentLogicalExpressions: true }],
        'react/jsx-filename-extension': [1, { extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'] }],
        'react/jsx-wrap-multilines': [
            'error',
            {
                declaration: 'parens-new-line',
                assignment: 'parens-new-line',
                return: 'parens-new-line',
                arrow: 'parens-new-line',
                condition: 'parens-new-line',
                logical: 'parens-new-line',
                prop: 'parens-new-line'
            }
        ],
        'prefer-arrow-callback': 'off',
        'prefer-arrow/prefer-arrow-functions': [
            'error',
            {
                disallowPrototype: true,
                singleReturnOnly: false,
                classPropertiesAllowed: false
            }
        ],
        'import/prefer-default-export': 'off',
        'import/extensions': [
            'error',
            'ignorePackages',
            {
                js: 'never',
                jsx: 'never',
                ts: 'never',
                tsx: 'never'
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

[image: MY ERROR]

Comment: anyone got an answer for this,